# accessing data in main project from a scheduledtaskagent

Tags: windows-phone-7

i would like to access data in my main project from the background agent project. The thing is that i can't add a refference to the background agent project because it will create a circular refference and that is not permited (i have a refference to the agent in the main project). How can i resolve this issue? Can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Your main application will not be running at the same time as your background agent, so you cannot communicate between the two. You can however share code between them, to do this you should place your common code within a class library. To do this, right click your solution and select "Add Project" => "Windows Phone Class Library"

Comment: Also, the shared code will have to comfort to strict limitations, as the Background Agent don't support all available classes. (This is first checked at marketplace approval).

Comment: @ClausJørgensen good point, do you know where these restrictions are detailed?

Comment: Here: [Unsupported APIs for Background Agents for Windows Phone (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962(v=VS.92).aspx)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Marketplace Test Kit tool which is part of the SDK contains an automated test which checks for restricted APIs in background agents.

Comment: It has to be said, Microsoft certainly got the tooling and overall development experience right for WP7.