# I want to use my code from my mainpage.xaml.cs to schduledagent.cs. is it possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use textblock1.text in my mainpage.xaml.cs to schduledagent.cs. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your main application will not be running at the same time as your background agent, so you cannot communicate between the two. You can however share code between them, to do this you should place your common code within a class library. To do this, right click your solution and select "Add Project" => "Windows Phone Class Library" (this is an answer from another thread) [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787964/accessing-data-in-main-project-from-a-scheduledtaskagent)

Comment: ok but I cannot use class project for keeping my common strings. for example I want to use string nec; by common between main project and schduleagent project. I tried but it didnT work. when I defined the string nec in class, I cannot see string nec in main or schdule project.

Comment: OK, remember that the isolated store in your case is a critical zone!